# How to separate flask-sqlalchemy models to different files? Models need to have db.Model. How do I pass it to a different file?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How to separate flask-sqlalchemy models to different files? Models need to have db.Model. How do I pass it to a different file?

All models need class ImageFileModel(**db**.Model):
How can I provide it in a different file?

```
    app = Flask(__name__) app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@192.168.56.101:5432/faceDetection' app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False FileHandler = FileHandler('logs/FlaskerrorLog.txt') FileHandler.setLevel(WARNING)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ImageFileModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True,autoincrement=False)
    #id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    type = db.Column(db.Integer) # 1 - abd, 2 - просто файлы
    md5 = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    sha1 = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    faces_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    JsonResponse = db.Column(db.String)
    error = db.Column(db.String)
    currentFace =  db.Column(db.Integer) #0 если только одно лицо вообще.
    filepath = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    url = db.Column(db.String) #тот url который будет показываться
    id_obj = db.Column(db.Integer)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ImageFileModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

How Can I save this model in a different file?

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you want to create the models, import the db

```
from <you app name> import db
```